# Sending data from php to a c# desktop application

Tags: c#, php

I am looking into doing a project which would involve php and c#. What I need to do is from PHP the user can perform a certain task and once php has processed some information, this information needs to be sent to a c# application and c# can do some other work with the information provided.

The c# application would most likely work from the same server that the php web app is running from but it should work if they are on completely separate servers.

I guess I could send some XML from php to whatever IP address that the c# program running on, but have no idea how I would get php to do the sending and the c# app to do the listing for the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOAP

In one acronym, you have the solution to (almost) any interoperability problem in your life.

"Simply" define a web service running in a desktop application (**it is possible** but it's not that straightforward) and instantiate a PHP [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php).

### XML (pure)

Of course you can send direct XML input to your desktop application. This makes use of .NET Socket (`System.Net.Sockets`) and PHP socket I/O (`fsockopen`). You can create your application-specific protocol and inject the XML data.

Recommended if you are already very familiar with XML and comfortable to sockets.
Unrecommended if you want a higher level of reusability.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify the nature of the data you're sending but if you're sending it across the web, then using language-independent methods such as XML, JSON, web services and the like means your server-side languages are largely irrelevant.

If you're sending something like huge movie files, however, then you'll probably be better off using FTP or similar.

Comment: The data would be just some variables with information in, nothing big

Comment: Then XML, JSON, etc. will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could open a WCF channel in the C# service and then call into it with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should host a [self host WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) in your desktop application and call the services from your php application.

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
```

sample code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
   [OperationContract]
   string SayHello(string name);
}

public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
  public string SayHello(string name)
  {
    return string.Format("Hello, {0}", name);
  }
}
```